# When considering vector spaces $A$ and $B$, what is the difference between $A \times B,$ $A \otimes B$ and $A \wedge B?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

I have looked at this resource http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/tensorproduct.pdf to instinctively differentiate between the tensor product and the direct sum of two vector spaces.

I am currently working on Lie Algebras. Some resources tell me that the Lie Bracket $[\cdot, \cdot]: \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g},$ whereas some tell me that $[\cdot, \cdot]:\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}.$ Are these definitions in fact equivalent? If so why? What does the tensor product add information wise that the standard product does not?

Finally, is there any relation between the tensor product and the wedge product?

Comment: Remember that bilinear maps $\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with linear maps $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$, so it doesn't really matter in which way we view the Lie bracket

Comment: Of course, thank you! In general though, why would one use one or the other?

Comment: Bilinear forms are easier to explicitly compute for arbitrary elements, but a linear map from the tensor product of spaces has all the niceness of a linear map

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is there a similar property with the relation between tensor product and wedge product?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lie bracket is an alternating bilinear map. This means you can describe it in three different ways:

- As a function $\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ (which is alternating and bilinear),
- As a linear map $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ (which is alternating), or
- As a linear map $\Lambda^2 \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$.

(Here I'm ignoring the Jacobi identity.) In the first piece of notation, $\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g}$ denotes a *set*, not a vector space. One reason to introduce the tensor product is to have the ability to talk about bilinear maps in a way which stays entirely "inside" vector spaces, without mentioning sets.

There is no such thing as the wedge product of two vector spaces. There is such a thing as the exterior powers $\Lambda^k V$ of a vector space. I guess some people denote $\Lambda^2 V$ by $V \wedge V$, but in my opinion this is a very bad idea, as it suggests (incorrectly) that there's such a thing as $V \wedge W$.

Comment: Well $\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g}$ is a vector space (the product of $\mathfrak{g}$ with itself); I guess what you want to mean is that the map coming from the product is not a map from vector spaces, and $\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g}$ is not usefully regarded as a vector space here? (I'm not sure how it should be regarded -- probably a pair of objects in the multicategory $\mathsf{MultiLin}$)

Comment: @Najib: yes and yes.

Comment: So we can say:

A Lie algebra is a vector space $\mathfrak{g}$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ together with a binary operation $[\cdot, \cdot]: \wedge^2\mathfrak{g} \to {g},$ such that the Jacobi Identity is satisfied.

Comment: the main reason I am asking is I am looking at the dual map. If we have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g},$ the the dual space $\mathfrak{g^*}$ is a Lie algebra with Lie bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]_{\mathfrak{g^*}}: \mathfrak{g^*} \otimes \mathfrak{g^*} \to \mathfrak{g^*}.$ Then define the dual map $\beta: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g},$ defined by $\beta(X) = \sum_{i=1}^k Y_i \wedge Z_i.$ I basically wanted to know why $\beta: \mathfrak{g}$ to $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g},$ rather than to $\mathfrak{g} \wedge \mathfrak{g}.$

Comment: @Halo: it is certainly not true that the linear dual of a Lie algebra is another Lie algebra. Again, you can regard the codomain of the Lie bracket as being either $\mathfrak{g} \otimes \mathfrak{g}$ or $\Lambda^2 \mathfrak{g}$. These are two different linear maps (which encode the same information), and they have two different linear duals (which also encode the same information).